# Change the way the locale is displayed in url with Symfony3

Tags: symfony, routes, localization

Symfony3 displays by default local in url in that way : `website.com/en_GB/` (or "en_gb").

How to change that to display it in that way: `website.com/en-gb/` ?

With the below controller and calling to `website.com/en-GB/` returns the homepage in French (default language is French). Calling to `website.com/en_GB/` returns the page in English.

en_GB : english of UK

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/", name="homepageLocale")
 * @Template("AppBundle:Default:homepage/homepage.html.twig")
 */
 public function homepageLocaleAction(Request $request) {
    return [];
 }
```

It's seems that the code decoding the locale is that one:

```
   Symfony\Component\Intl\Locale.php

   public static function getFallback($locale)
    {
        if (false === $pos = strrpos($locale, '_')) {
            if (self::$defaultFallback === $locale) {
                return 'root';
            }

            // Don't return default fallback for "root", "meta" or others
            // Normal locales have two or three letters
            if (strlen($locale) < 4) {
                return self::$defaultFallback;
            }

            return;
        }

        return substr($locale, 0, $pos);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you might need decorate "completely" [the HttpKernel `LocaleListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/LocaleListener.php) to something like this:

```
// AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener

private function setLocale(Request $request)
{
    if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
        if (false !== strpos($locale, '-')) {
            // translate en-gb to en_GB
            $localeParts = explode('-', $locale);
            $locale = $localeParts[0].'_'.strtoupper($localeParts[1]);
        }

        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }
}

private function setRouterContext(Request $request)
{
    if (null !== $this->router) {
        $locale = $request->getLocale();

        // translate en_GB to en-gb
        $locale = strtolower(strtr($locale, '_', '-'));

        $this->router->getContext()->setParameter('_locale', $locale);
    }
}
```

**Note:** These two methods are `private`, it's why we need copy+paste the complete code of the original listener to change its behavior.

More about ["How to Decorate Services" here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html), or creates you own [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to exchange the service class of the `locale_listener` definition.